# how to fix oracle ORA-01722 invalid number error

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, to-char

I have Oracle db with these inputs on column1(NUMBER(22,6)) in myTable.

```
0
199935,15
1026299
```

I want to display these columns like that:

```
00000000000000000.000000
00000000000199935.150000
00000000001026299.000000
```

My query:

```
SELECT trim(to_char(trim(replace(column1,',','.')),'9999999999999990.999999')) 
FROM myTable;
```

But Oracle shows this error. How can I fix?

```
01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
*Cause:    The specified number was invalid.
*Action:   Specify a valid number.
```

Comment: What is the type of your column? Is it a number or a string?

Comment: column1 type is NUMBER(22,6). Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a numeric column, all you have to do is use a [`to_char`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions217.htm#SQLRF06130) with the right parameters; this should do the work:

```
select to_char(column1, '00000000000000000D000000', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = ''.,''') from ...
```